# unable to parse json where key is having colon using jq

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

path/one is my location ...

I am trying to run this from Jenkins pipeline using groovy and bash

I am getting error unexpected token even i have enclosed key name (key name has colon) with quotes and square brackets. Dont know where i am making mistake. Please help

```
val = sh(script: "aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id path/one | jq --raw-output '.SecretString'  | jq --raw-output '.["Environment:BuildName"]' ",returnStdout: true).trim()   
echo "value is " + val
```

```
key: Environment:BuildName 
value : build-numbers
```

i have updated key and value of my secret keys consist...

Comment: Please provide an example JSON object that can be used in testing.

Comment: But you might need to escape the nested double quotes.

Comment: how to escape quotes  @shawn.

Comment: Dunno about jenkins, but backslashes are the usual way.

Comment: @reachit, show the sample output of `aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id path/one`

Comment: @daggett it looks like this as json key value pair  "Environment:BuildName": "apiartifact"

Comment: If I remember correctly, there is a nested json inside one of values. And you have to double parse it. So, if you want anyone to help, edit your question and provide a sample output. Of cause replace the sensitive info.